# ECharts: Trigger an event only when datazoom's slider drag action ends (left mouse button released)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, echarts

I want to select two values through the slider of datazoom in my line chart to filter elsewhere. Since filtering after selecting values takes a relatively long time each time, I cannot directly trigger the event through code below

```js
chart.on('datazoom', (params) => {
})
```

Because it will be executed many times. I want to trigger an event only after the slider is dragged to the end, that is, after the left mouse button is released. How should I implement this? I'll appreciated much if you could offer any suggestion!

Comment: The slider has a property [realtime](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom-slider.realtime) which only triggers the dataZoom event once if set to `false`

Comment: This property do help. Thanks a lot!